# Nextjs assets 404 Not Found when using dynamic rouitng while ssr

Tags: reactjs, next.js, assets, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing

I had a static folder with an older version of `nextjs`. I updated my `nextjs` to use `public` folder.

```
"next": "^9.4.0",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
```

this is my `nextjs` config:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');
require('dotenv').config();
const withSourceMaps = require('@zeit/next-source-maps')();

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  require.extensions['.css'] = file => {};
}

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    BUILD_ENV: process.env.BUILD_ENV,
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.resolve.alias['@sentry/node'] = '@sentry/browser';
    }

    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/;
      const origExternals = [...config.externals];
      config.externals = [ // eslint-disable-line
        (context, request, callback) => { // eslint-disable-line
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ];

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withImages],
    [withCss],
    [
      withSass,
      {
        cssModules: true,
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          localIdentName: '[path]___[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
    ],
    [withSourceMaps],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

When I refresh the page all my styles are like this:

[image]

I have a **dynamic page** called **[cat]**, so all the paths are like:

**http://localhost:3030/cat/static/css/antd.min.css**

Do you know how can I fix this?

When I route with Link everything is ok but when I refresh the page the assets are not found because of the dynamic route!

this is the directory:

[image]

Comment: Please show how exactly styles are included in the code and full path where browser is looking for assets (can see if you hover over entry in Network browser tab).

Comment: the full path is => http://localhost:3030/cat/static/css/antd.min.css

Comment: and the styles are imported normally (it works fine when click on Link but it cracks when refreshing the page)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was using [Next.js Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) to capture the URL path param but the CSS and JS assets would not load because it was prepending the path onto my Layout assets. i.e. in your sample, it would add `cat` in front of my asset's resource file path. My `pages` look something similar to: `pages/cats/[something].js`

I fixed this by adding a '/' to the resource path

Try correcting your Head/Layout

from:

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/antd.min.css" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/antd.min.css" />
```

This fixed my CSS and JS issues with displaying and pulling from the correct resource path link.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change the value of `src` from

```js
<img src="static/images/insta-1.jpg" alt="Insta1" width="83" height="83" />
```

to

```js
<img src="/static/images/insta-1.jpg" alt="Insta1" width="83" height="83" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but Nextjs doesn`t work with their own Image componenonent when dynamic routing.

The old html img tag works for me

`<img src={`${e.image.url}`} alt="punkies y cerebro showcase" />`